# Will previous account without MFA continue to work with Exchange Online PowerShell V2 (EXO V2) module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, exchange-basicauth, o365security-compliance

For our solution we use EXO V1. We use an account that does not have MFA enabled to create a session with O365 exchange as a service to get exchange(O365) information.
Now we were planning to migrate to EXO V2. We wanted to understand will our solution continue to work with the previous account when we migrate to EXO V2?

We did try this an for a test account and it worked. But the risk we see is the MSDN page saying ,'***You can't use Basic authentication in the EXO V2 module;***'.
Refer the EXO V2 page here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#how-the-exo-v2-module-works

The support for appId\certificate based authentication to run(app id, secret etc.) this in a service is in EXO preview I guess and we don't want to migrate to using the preview yet.

Can someone please confirm if we can safely move to using EXO V2 from EXO V1 with the same account without any config changes from O365 side etc.?

Also any idea on when EXO V2 preview can be GA?

Comment: You can safely migrate to EXO V2. The features EXO V1 has have been provided by EXO V2. You don't need other additional configurations. appId\certificate based authentication has been available in current release: Version 2.0.3. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#current-release-version-203.

Comment: Hi do you still need help on this issue? Is my comment helpful?

Comment: @AllenWu, thank you for your comment. This was helpful. I also got an answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/103565/will-previous-account-without-mfa-continue-to-work.html which also suggests the same. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm glad to know your question has been clarified with my comment and that answer from other place. In order to help more people who have the same question, I'll move my comment to answer. You can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely migrate to EXO V2.

The features EXO V1 has have been provided by EXO V2.

Without MFA configuration, you don't need other additional configurations.

And appId\certificate based authentication has been available in current release: Version 2.0.3.

See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#current-release-version-203).